# Term for competition where time difference of two rounds should be zero

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a type of competition where you walk or run (or even cycle) two rounds in a predefined course, and the purpose is to use the exact same time in both rounds. You will get a penalty equal to the seconds you are off, and the result list is based on how little/much penalty the competitors have got.

In Norwegian this is called "nulløp", directly translated that becomes "zero run" (after the ideal of having zero time difference), but "zero run" does not seem to be what I am looking for.

Sample sentence:
*"We are arranging a WORD this weekend."*

Does anyone know what this type of competition is called in English?

Comment: The condition OP points out to is similar to the Dressage. I could not find any specific term for such competition, however, I think "fixed-time" competition can be an appropriate (but not the perfect) term.

Comment: I think you will just have to invent a word. I would suggest ***nullop***, as this is what is used for the website. If you wanted a catchy geeky phrase, I might suggest ***ZVR*** for ***Z**ero **V**ariance **R**ace*.

Comment: BTW, are ties broken by who is faster?

Comment: Thanks for your replies and suggestions! @Eilia, when you say "the Dressage", do you mean the horse riding? 

I also found something called "regularity rally", which is in the same category, but then you set a predefined time, and drive the course once and aiming for the predefined time. 

I think both "fixed-time" and the more geeky suggestion, ZVR, could fit. "nullop" may not make much sense outside the Nordic countries.

Ties are usually just ties, who is faster does not matter.

Comment: @Michael, Yes, I mean an equestrian sport.

Comment: AFAIK, this type of competition isn't common in America, so there may be no AmE word for it. If you need to come up with a word, I'd suggest basing it on the word "consistent", since you're being scored based on how consistent your timings are.

Comment: Further to Barmar's Comment, AFAIK, this type of competition isn't common in British or any other form of English and although I'm no horseman, I suggest that "dressage" suggestion is no better founded.

Why not just copy "nulløp", even though to me it seems very obvious that "nulløp" directly translated could never become anything like "zero run"?

Comment: Regarding "nulløp" and direct translation: the word is a compound (which is  common in Norwegian and other North Germanic languages) and consists of the two words "null" (the number zero) and "løp" (run/race), when a compound results in three equal letters in a row they will be truncated to two letters, hence "nulløp" and not "nullløp".